# cld() function does not work anymore with emmGrid class object from emmeans package

Tags: r, emmeans

My previous code that worked with the `cld()` function from the `multcomp` package and the `emmGrid` class objects obtained from the `emmeans()` function from the `emmeans` package no longer works. Now I get this error message:

> `Error in UseMethod("cld") :  no applicable method for 'cld' applied to an object of class "emmGrid"`

Here a reproducible example :

```
if(requireNamespace("multcomp"))
{
  emm_example("cld-multcomp")
}
```

I know that `emmeans` package has recently been updated. I use the 1.8.2 version of the `emmeans` package. My R version is 4.2.2 "Innocent and Trusting"

Can you help me with that?

P.S. I downgraded to version 1.8.0 of the `emmeans` package and it works again...

Comment: The code example runs fine on my pc after updating _both_ emmeans and multcomp.

Comment: with the version 1.8.2 of emmeans and the new version of R (4.2.2)?

Comment: Yes, version 4.2.2 of R, version 1.8.2 emmeans and version 1.4-20 of multcomp. In a fresh session, running `emm_example("cld-multcomp")` works as expected with no error (I'm on Windows with platform x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

Comment: Ok Thank you! That's weird. Maybe I'll edit this later, if I find what happens.

Comment: Version 1.8.2 was built under R 4.2.1 anyway. But version 1.8.2 of **emmeans** *could not* have made it to CRAN if this did not work, since it is one of the provided examples which are all tested. I suggest quitting and restarting R.