# compact letter display multcomp::cld() does not work for emmeans list (emmList) or grid (emmGrid) object

Tags: r, statistics

I need to display compact letters for p.values of contrasts, but emmeans package does not support it anymore.

here's the reproducible example:

```
pigs.lm <- lm(log(conc) ~ source + factor(percent), data = pigs)

pigs.emm <- emmeans(pigs.lm, "percent", type = "response")

multcomp::cld(pigs.emm, alpha = 0.10, Letters = LETTERS)
```

I read [cld() function does not work anymore with emmGrid class object from emmeans package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74295423/cld-function-does-not-work-anymore-with-emmgrid-class-object-from-emmeans-pack) but could not find a way to make it work.

Comment: The example you give works just fine for me. Perhaps you need to restart R, or reinstall a package.